# Small (elementary) confusion regarding affine algebraic sets.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If we have a non-constant polynomial $f_\in k[T_1]$ and we look at the affine variety $D(f)\subseteq \mathbb{A}^1_k$, then it's affine coordinate ring is $\Gamma(D(f))=k[T_1]_f\cong k[T_1,T_2]/(1-fT_2)$ as $k$-algebras, hence we have that by the equivalence of reduced finitely generated $k$-algebras and affine algebraic sets, that $D(f)\cong V(1-fT_2)\subseteq \mathbb{A}^2_k$ as affine algebraic sets. However, the "obvious" map $x\mapsto (x,f(x)^{-1})$ is in general not given by polynomials, so it can't serve as the isomorphism. My question is if everything that I wrote so far is correct - or rather where the mistakes are - and maybe to get some help to resolve my confusion, because for my eyes it seems as though the $k$-algebra isomorphism is canonical, so I would expect also a canonical isomorphism on the level of affine algebraic sets. I'm quite sure that I have a substantial misunderstanding here, so that's why I'm asking. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that $D(f)\subset \Bbb A^1$ is not an affine algebraic set, because it's not the zero locus of some collection of polynomials in $k[T_1]$. On the other hand, everything you say is true if you enlarge your category a bit by looking at quasi-affine algebraic sets (open subsets of algebraic sets) where the morphisms are given by regular functions (each component is locally the quotient of two polynomials where the denominator does not vanish). Once you make this upgrade, it's clear that the map you write down is in fact a morphism in this category, and it's actually an isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you very much - that was the kind of clarification I was hoping for!